# Key is not being released on very short keypresses

Tags: keyboard, hardware

On my keyboard, when I press a key very lightly and release it quickly (talking about probably 0.1s of button press here), the key does not issue a release event correctly and instead typed repeatedly if key repeat is turned on - as if I had never let go of the key. 
It's quite hard to do it intentionally but it happens enough to be a quite nuisance.

I've tested the key events using `xev`. There's no difference between actually keeping the key pressed and releasing it in such a matter that no release event is issued.
My keyboard does not do this under Windows, I suspect there might be some kind of driver problem(?).

**Note/Workaround:**
For now, I've gone to only enabling key repeat on my arrow keys and backspaces because that's the only place I need. `xset -r [keycode]` does work correctly when key repeat is turned on in the gnome settings, otherwise it doesn't. I'm pretty certain that this information is non-relevant to solving the problem but if any one else has this issue they might find it helpful.

My OS is Fedora 22, latest version. I have a Dell XPS 13 9343 (2015 model).

Edit: 
Output for `dmidecode -t bios -q`:

```
sudo dmidecode -t bios -q
BIOS Information
Vendor: Dell Inc.
Version: A00
Release Date: 11/04/2014
Address: 0xF0000
Runtime Size: 64 kB
ROM Size: 8192 kB
Characteristics:
    PCI is supported
    PNP is supported
    BIOS is upgradeable
    BIOS shadowing is allowed
    Boot from CD is supported
    Selectable boot is supported
    EDD is supported
    5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
    3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
    3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
    Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
    8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
    Serial services are supported (int 14h)
    Printer services are supported (int 17h)
    ACPI is supported
    USB legacy is supported
    Smart battery is supported
    BIOS boot specification is supported
    Function key-initiated network boot is supported
    Targeted content distribution is supported
    UEFI is supported
BIOS Revision: 5.6

BIOS Language Information
Language Description Format: Long
Installable Languages: 1
    en|US|iso8859-1
Currently Installed Language: en|US|iso8859-1
```

Comment: What id your BIOS version? `dmidecode -t bios -q` What model? XPS 13 ??? (9333, 9343, 9350, L321K, L322X)

Comment: @Sukminder My model is 9343. I added the information to my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is likely due to a HW / (and|or) / BIOS issue.

- [XPS 13 (9343) unwanted keyboard character repeat](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN297563/EN)

Your BIOS version is [A00](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=TXPFH), which was initial release. The current release is [A07](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=28M21). Keyboard issue was fixed in A05+.

You would likely want to follow [this site](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/xps-13-9343-laptop/drivers/advanced?rvps=y), the Product Support page for your model, (or the like).

[This](https://github.com/mpalourdio/xps13) is a development repository targeting Linux, which also have some links you might find interesting. Here the key-repeat issue is also mentioned.

---

#### BIOS releases:

A short re-cap on changes and release info from DELL. Not the best of change-logs though.

- **[A00](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=TXPFH)**, 13 Jan 2015 (Optional :)

  - Initial Release
- **[A01](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=RHPC0)**, 25 Feb 2015 (Optional)

  1. Update CPU Microcode 0x306D4 to Rev 0x18.
  2. Update ePSA to4236.24.
- **[A02](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=F2PRR)**, 22 Mar 2015 (Recommended)

  1. Update Fan management
  2. Update Intel CPU microcode
- **[A03](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=XY677)**, 30 Mar 2015 (Recommended)

  1. Fix I3-5010 CPU performance issue.
- **[A04](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=133FN)**, 25 May 2015 (Recommended)

  1. *Improved Keyboard behavior*
  2. Update CPU Microcode.
- **[A05](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=YMRTD)**, 31 Jul 2015 (Urgent)

  1. *Improved Keyboard behavior*
  2. Update CPU Microcode.
  3. WIN10 BIOS Support
- **A06** (Did they jump directly to A07?)
- **[A07](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=28M21)**, 26 Nov 2015 (Recommended)

  1. *Improve Double Key issue*
  2. Add Support for Ubuntu PTT feature